# how to deal with the sign string and get what you want?

Tags: android, html, string

now my `string` is “*app*le,b*na*na”. I want to find the `string` which contains with "* *" and highlight it and remove “* *” in the same time in android. for example: the `string` "*app*le,b*na*na" handle it and get
"**app**le,b**na**na". I am in trouble with remove the "**". maybe I think highlight it and remove "**" is conflict.

my code as flow:

```
    Matcher matcher = PatternMatcherUtil.matcherHighlight(words);
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder(words);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        spannableString.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mHost.getContext(),
                        R.color.phonics_content_highlight_color)),
                matcher.start() + 1, matcher.end() - 1,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    textView.setText(spannableString);



    public class PatternMatcherUtil {

    private static final String REGEX = "(\\*\\w+\\*)+";

    public static Matcher matcherHighlight(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        return pattern.matcher(input);
     }
   }
```

I only get "***app***le,b***na***na", this is not what I want ,Could somebody can help me.I shall be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check if your string "s" contains "*"       
if(s.contains("*")) {
//contains
    s.replace("*", "");//replaces all "*" with empty
}
Log.d("NewString",s);
```

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle Sure

Comment: That's a lot better! I've edited to clarify the code sample a little; feel free to roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: yeah, your answer give me the inspiration. I just deal with the variable “spannableString” and replace it ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the code , it can solve my problem. But I want know there is any better way to solve it?

```
    Matcher matcher = PatternMatcherUtil.matcherHighlight(words);
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder(words);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        spannableString.setSpan(
                new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(mHost.getContext(),
                        R.color.phonics_content_highlight_color)),
                matcher.start() + 1, matcher.end() - 1,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    //add the code you will solve the problem.
    for(int j = 0; j < spannableString.length(); j++) {
                    if(spannableString.charAt(j) == '*') {
                        spannableString.replace(j, j + 1, "");
                    }
                }
    textView.setText(spannableString);



    public class PatternMatcherUtil {

    private static final String REGEX = "(\\*\\w+\\*)+";

    public static Matcher matcherHighlight(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        return pattern.matcher(input);
     }
   }
```